# Azure Host WCF webrole AND MVC webrole?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

I have two projects in my solution that I would like to publish to Azure as a Cloudapp.

1. MVC webrole, (service reference to WCF webrole)
2. WCF webrole

Now, is it not possible to publish two webroles in one Cloudapp? (Dah, dumb question).

**If not possible, how am I supposed to use my WCF service? Am I force to publish the WCF service as it's own cloudapp!?**

**Perhaps it is possible to publish the WCF service as a worker role so I don't have to use two cloudapps for this?**

Currently everything is working great locally. I have added a service reference in my MVC project pointing to my WCF service and I'm able to use the functions that resides in there.

The problem is that the WCF webrole doesn't get published, (just the MVC webrole). I can't access the WCF service, (The resource cannot be found).

Do you have any suggestions on how I can implement my WCF service when published without too much of a hassle?

Thanks

Comment: if its causing any problem host it in a worker role , you need internal communication just add an internal endpoint your worker role

Comment: Any downsides with using a worker role? I want to use the WCF service for every database call, (DTO objects), so it'll be used very very frequently.

Comment: There is no downside whatsover you can use any type of binding ,, will you be calling your service fyour MVC APP or from outside client?

Comment: Then using a worker role to host your WCF is a better solution since web role services are by default public and you don't want other people to temper with your service , just use internal endpoints when hosting your service , and you can even use nettcp binding

Comment: I'm following a guide on codeprojects but I have encountered some problems. How are you supposed to add a service reference to the wcf service through the worker role? Do you have skype or anything else i can contact you on? Really appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74732/discussion-between-coder1409-and-reft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host your WCF service in a worker role. Thank you, Coder1409!

Heres a follow up question:
**[Host WCF in the Worker Role, Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536463/host-wcf-in-the-worker-role-timeout)**