# Host WCF in the Worker Role, Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

Basically, I'm following this: [GUIDE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azure-wcf-in-the-worker-role/)

What I want is to publish my Cloudapp to azure with one **web role** and one **worker role**.

**Worker role**

I'm hosting a WCF service in my worker role where all the sql communication will happen, (DTO objects).

**Web role**

My web role project is just a normal MVC app that has a service reference to the WCF service. For an example, if a user wants to register, the data is sent to the WCF service which then sends it to the DB.

**Problem**

Error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

I also got a timeout error before which I can't seem to reproduce anymore..

I have followed the guide very thoroughly. The one thing that is different is that I would like to host them in one publish, not two. Also, the guy publish the project by clicking on packages which I don't, (I click on publish button).

I'm all out of ideas. I have only found two guides about hosting your WCF service in a worker role, the one I'm following now and [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188464/Host-WCF-Services-in-an-Azure-Worker-Role) one. Both are very outdated and doesn't really do what I want to do. Both guides host the WCF service as a standalone Cloudapp. What I want is to publish both the worker role and the web role in the same solution, **one** publish.

If you have any suggestions, please leave them here. I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you very much.

*/Dying programmer*

**EDIT 1 - CODE -**

**INTERFACE & IMPLEMENTATION**

```
namespace Fildela_Worker
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFildelaService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void InsertUser(UserDTO user);
    }
}
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=tru‌​e)]
public class FildelaService : IFildelaService
    {
        DataLayer DB = new DataLayer();

        public void InsertUser(UserDTO user)
        {
            User newUser = new User(user.FirstName.ToLower().Trim(), user.LastName.ToLower().Trim(),
                user.Email.ToLower().Trim(), user.Password.Trim(), user.PasswordSalt.Trim(), user.AgreeUserAgreement);

            DB.User.Add(newUser);
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

**SERVICE DEFINITION**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Fildela_Web.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <WebRole name="Fildela Web" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
  <WorkerRole name="Fildela Worker" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="port" protocol="tcp" port="9001" />
      <InputEndpoint name="mexport" protocol="tcp" port="8001" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

**WORKER ROLE ONSTART:**

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        // Create the host
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FildelaService));

        // Read config parameters
        string hostName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint.Address.ToString();
        int port = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint.Port;
        int mexport = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["mexport"].IPEndpoint.Port;

        // Create Metadata
        ServiceMetadataBehavior metadatabehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadatabehavior);

        Binding mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
        string mexendpointurl = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/FildelaServiceMetadata", hostName, 8001);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexBinding, mexendpointurl, new Uri(mexendpointurl));

        // Create end point
        string endpointurl = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/FildelaService", hostName, 9001);
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFildelaService), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), endpointurl, new Uri(endpointurl));

        // Open the host
        host.Open();

        // Trace output
        Trace.WriteLine("WCF Listening At: " + endpointurl);
        Trace.WriteLine("WCF MetaData Listening At: " + mexendpointurl);

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

**MVC WEB.CONFIG:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IFildelaService">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://MYADDRESS.cloudapp.net:9001/FildelaService"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IFildelaService"
        contract="FildelaServiceReference.IFildelaService" name="NetTcpBinding_IFildelaService" />
    </client>
....
```

**MVC PROXY USE:**

```
FildelaServiceClient proxy = new FildelaServiceClient();

                                UserDTO newUser = new UserDTO()
                                {
parameters....
                                };

                                //Insert user
proxy.InsertAccountOwner(newUser);
```

**EDIT 2 - CODE -**

**Worker role**

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        StartWCFHost();

        return base.OnStart();
    }

private void StartWCFHost()
{
    var baseaddress = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/", RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["FildelaService"].IPEndpoint);
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FildelaService), new Uri(baseaddress));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFildelaService), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "Database");
    host.Open();
}
```

**ServiceDefinition**

```
<WorkerRole name="Fildela Worker" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint name="FildelaService" protocol="tcp" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WorkerRole>
```

**Controller**

```
private EndpointAddress GetRandomEndpoint()
    {
        var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["Fildela Worker"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["FildelaService"].IPEndpoint).ToArray();
        var r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        return new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Database", endpoints[r.Next(endpoints.Count() - 1)]));
    }





[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ViewResult Contact()
    {
        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IFildelaService>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None));
        factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel(GetRandomEndpoint());

        List<CategoryDTO> contactCategories = channel.GetContactCategories().ToList();

        return View(contactCategories);
    }
```

Comment: can you show me the code you're using for hosting the webservice and the code you are using to call the webservice

Comment: Hey! Thanks for showing interest. Check my edit, all my code is there! Tell  if I have missed something:)

Comment: Check my Answer for the right simple way to do it

Comment: And What error are you getting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have the contract and service , to host your service delete all the code you have added to your OnStart methode and add this methode

```
 private void StartWCFHost()
    {
        var baseaddress = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/", RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint);
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FildelaService), new Uri (baseaddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFildelaService), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "Inserter");
        host.Open();
    }
```

That is it just call this method from your OnStart method and the host is done

Now the question is about consuming the webservice

in your controller when you are calling the webservice add this code (we're creating a Channel factory no need to add service reference)

First add this method to your controller

```
 private EndpointAddress GetRandomEndpoint()
    {
        var endpoints= RoleEnvironment.Roles["PutWorkerRoleName"].Instances.Select(i=>i.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint).ToArray();
        var r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        return new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Inserter", endpoints[r.Next(endpoints.Count() - 1)]));
    }
```

then add this code to call the service in your controller method(since you're using MVC)

```
 var factory = new ChannelFactory<IFildelaService>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None));
        var channel = factory.CreateChannel(GetRandomEndpoint());
        channel.InsertAccountOwner(newUser);
```

I may have forgotten to rename some variables from my working project so feel free to verify the conformity of your code

**Update**

I uploaded the project to my github :
[Worker Role WCF host+Web Role](https://github.com/adimo1409/WorkerRoleHoster)

Comment: I don't have the time right now to test the code. I will probably test it tonight so i will get back to you then. Big thanks!

Comment: Additional information: 'maxValue' must be greater than zero.

var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["Fildela Worker"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["port"].IPEndpoint).ToArray();

Gives 0 results, (counts). The worker name is correct. What am i missing? Thanks

Comment: Well for one you are using an input endpoint while you should use an internal one , your name is kinda messed up try something like FildelaWorker to avoid string problems , just start a new project and follow the template i created in githbub : https://github.com/adimo1409/WorkerRoleHoster

Comment: As you can see I have never done this before. Input endpoint? Internal endpoint? Can you explain this? I have followed your code here exactly as you have written it, shouldn't it work? There is nothing wrong with the worker role name, if I change it to something else it says "key not found" instead so that is not the problem, (I have tried with a different name aswell). I'm almost ready to accept your answer, but first I would like my service to be functional. Thanks

Comment: When you declare your endpoint make it internal which is used for inter Role communication, just go to your AzureProject -> click on your worker host and go the endpoint , click add endpoint , give it a name and choose internal , spevify tcp and a port ,,, and it should work , you could look for more details in the code in github or even testit since it is working for me

Comment: Alright that helped and made sense.. However I got a new exception now, (sorry).

--- [EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:20000/Inserter. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0392016. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:20000. ]

Comment: Please update your code after the changes, how did you name your endpoint ?

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2 above. Sorry for asking so much.. This gives me error: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  (published) and error: Additional information: This request operation sent to net.tcp://127.0.0.1:20000/Database did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00) (localhost) ..... Thank you once again

Comment: Why the request is being sent to localhost??

Comment: The first error is when published to azure, (not localhost). The second error is when the project is run locally, (you can probably ignore this error). ERROR NOW: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: ok let's inspect the error message exactly , go to your service defintion and add this [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)], I will edit your answer with suggested modifications

Comment: This is what I got after adding includeexception:
This request operation sent to net.tcp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:20001/Database did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

Comment: I have not added: factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); yet, (I am publishing now, cloudapp takes some time to publish so bear with me :P)

Comment: have you added this factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);??

Comment: There we go. Now I'm getting: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)...

Comment: In this case just check your SQL connection ? try to return some random List just to confirm the Service is working properly instead of asking the database

Comment: Apparently I had my connectionstring in my old WCF project which I don't use anymore. If i want to specify my conncetionstring in a config file and not in the role, where should I put it? In my worker role project or my mvc project, (webconfig)?

Comment: Just put it where you are using ur database in you worker role web.config

Comment: Working now! Thank you so much man, wouldn't have made it without you! One absolut final question, I promise I will stop bothering you and accept your answer after this!

Question: Must I create a channel everytime a user wants to connect to the DB through my actions? Can I somehow put it in an extension? Creating a factory and a channel in all my actions would add alot of code.

Comment: I believe you can do it , never had to do it since it has never bothered me creating a channel returning a random endpoint each time , but just try and see , make sure your channel is accessible and it should work ,good luck

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again Coder but I have one important question for you if you don't mind. How do I update/regenerate the channel? I've added a couple of functions in my interface and my implementation but it doesn't want to update itself so I can never reach my functions. Have I forgotten something?

Comment: Just update the contract you're using with your channel and the methods will appear as they should

Comment: I have added a operationcontract and the implementation, as I always have done, but it wont show up for some reason? If i look in my web project there is a servicereference, is that auto generated from my channel or is it leftover code from my previous proxy (?)

Comment: Just check you're using the right updated interface with your channel , there is no update needed

Comment: Thanks! Apparently when I was creating a channel i was referencing my interface in the Service Reference and not the interface in my worker project. I changed it so i am now refering to my worker projekt, this is correct, yes? Works now anyways!

Comment: Yeah exactly , that's what i was explaining

Comment: In my worker project where my Interface and my implementation resides, I have two reference to two other projects in my solution: Datalayer, (database context class) and Datalayer models (database models). Everything works fine on localhost, but when I publish to Azure I get an exception everytime I try to call the database. If I move my datalayer and datalayer models to my worker project everything works and I dont get an exception, (one projects in the solution instead of three). How you encountered this problem? The exception im getting is: (check next comment)!

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'DataLayer Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 - AND - Could not load file or assembly 'DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. - - - - - I am not missing any DLL files and everything works on localhost. If  I move my datalayer and datayaler models to my worker roles everything works again.